# OpenCV with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing, opencv, android-ndk

I'm just after setting up OpenCV for android in Eclipse following this [tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html), I have the samples which do not use native c running fine on my phone.

The problem is when I try to run the native code samples, I followed all the steps on the [next](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk) page for setting up the builder in eclipse but when I try to run the samples on my phone they crash. I have used NDK before and successfully set up tesseract for android using the command line to compile the native code instead of eclipse.

I think the problem is due to

`unsatisfiedLinkError:Couldn't load native_sample:findLibrary returned null`

but I am unsure. I have a screenshot [here](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7191/screenshotat20120226231.png) if that helps.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome !!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is a native_sample.so in your APK, it seems the java app can not load your lib.

Comment: Which directory should it be located in? I have libnative_camera_r2.so / r2.3.3.so and libnative_sample.so in the libs folder if that's what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

I'm late here, but you need to place any `.so` files in your `libs/armeabi` folder in order for Android to find them.